# File upload field in admin page does not have value when editing

Tags: admin, adminform, file-upload

I created a form and it only contains a file upload field. Uploading new file works properly. However, when I want to edit the record, the file upload field shows "No file chosen", and when I go to save the record without choosing the file, it warns me to select a file since it is a required field. My question is how to put the value from database and prevent it from modification when no new file is chosen?

Thank you in advance.

Here is my code

```
    class Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Fileupload_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {

    protected function _prepareForm() {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);

        if(Mage::registry('fileupload_data')) {
            $data = Mage::registry('fileupload_data')->getData();
        }

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldSet('fileupload_form', array('legend' => 'File Upload'));

        if(isset($data['filepath']) && $data['filepath']) {
            $fileName = $data['filepath'];
            $data['filepath'] = 'directory'.'/'.$fileifName;
        }

        $fieldset->addField('filepath', 'file', array(
            'label' => 'File',
            'name' => 'filepath',
            'index' => 'filepath',
            'required' => true
        ));

        $form->setValues($data);
        return parent::_prepareForm();

    }

}
```

**Update:**

editAction

```
public function editAction() {
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $model = Mage::getModel('model/files')->load($id);
    if($model->getId() || $id == 0) {
        $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);
        if(!empty($data)) {
            $model->setData($data);
        }
        Mage::register('fileupload_data', $model);
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('fileupload/fileupload');
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('fileupload/adminhtml_fileupload_edit'))
                ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('fileupload/adminhtml_fileupload_edit_tabs'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    } else {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('File does not exist');
    }

}
```

Comment: `'name' => 'filepath',` this must be your database column name or have the value of file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 'filepath' is the column name in database. Is there any rule for the value of this column?

Comment: check the value are set for that just do the inspect elemet you will see a hidden `<input type="hidden" value="your value" name="filepath[value]">`

Comment: share your `editAction` code too..

Comment: are you trying to upload image or file?

Comment: I checked the html tag and the value in "value" is as desired, which is "directory/filename.pdf". The code of editAction has been uploaded. I want to upload a pdf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code instead for that for edit don't add validation classes.

```
$setting = array(
        'label'     => 'File',
        'name'      => 'filepath',
    );
    if (!Mage::registry('fileupload_data')->getId()){// if on "add" mode (use the same registry key as in your admin controller)
        $settings['required'] = true;
        $settings['class'] = 'required-entry';
    }
    $fieldset->addField('filepath', 'file', $setting);
```

Comment: Where to add the code? In editAction?

Comment: in your save action where you upload the file use else statement if the use not upload the file.

Comment: However, the input field is required. I cannot pass the validation.

Comment: 'class'     => 'required-entry required-file',  add this class on file.

Comment: It does not work. It still requires me to choose a file.

Comment: update the code try it..

Comment: I got your logic. I think it works. Thank you!